# Assigning Pandas categories to new number

Tags: python, pandas, binning

```
df["A"].value_counts()

(25.0, 38.0]      361594
(12.999, 25.0]    330552
(55.0, 218.0]     305439
(38.0, 55.0]      231683
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

we have following interval , whenever a new datapoint is coming I need to map to the following above interval . I want something like this .

```
def func_(x):
    if (x> 12.999) & (x< 25.0):
      return (12.999, 25.0]
    elif:
        for rest of bucket range
```

Comment: Can you provide a constructor to get the initial Series?

Comment: so basically pandas qcut has been used for identifying the range . pd.qcut()

Comment: I get it, but it would be nice not to have to type it manually ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse `bins` parameter by categories generated by [`CategoricalIndex.categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.categories.html):

```
s = df["A"].value_counts()

print (pd.cut(df['new'], bins=s.index.categories))
```